# Notification icon appearing small in Android

Tags: android

[image: see this image]I'm trying to add icon to the notification, but the notification icon comes very small and doesn't cover up the entire space.

I've right image sizes in each resource folder.

The code that I've for notification:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Lock.class);
         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(), 
                0, 
                myIntent, 
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

         myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
           .setContentTitle("Invisible Screen Lock")
           .setContentText("Lock Your Screen")
           .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
           .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
           .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.launcher)
           .setOngoing(true)
           .build();

         notificationManager = 
           (NotificationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
         notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);
```

How can I make the icon appear correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setLargeIcon(icon) as follow:

```
myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
       .setContentTitle("Invisible Screen Lock")
       .setContentText("Lock Your Screen")
       .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
       .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
       .setLargeIcon(icon)
       .setOngoing(true)
       .build();
```

Comment: how to set the value of the variable name icon in .setLargeIcon() ??

Comment: You need to pass bitmap of your icon. .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.launcher));

Comment: I added this, the icon appears when I draw the notification bar down, but without drawing the notification bar down the icon does appear. I hope you get what I am trying to say.

Comment: I don't know what you are saying.

Comment: I have added an image in the edited question, you might now understand what i was trying to say earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving a Large Icon

```
    Notification.Builder nb = new Notification.Builder(context)
    .setContentTitle("title")
    .setContentText("content")
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setLargeIcon(drawableToBitmap(YOUR_DRAWABLE))
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_icon)
    .setTicker(s.getText());
   NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   nm.notify(100, nb.build());
```

add this method

```
public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
        if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
            return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        }
    }

    if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
    } else {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: how do i set the value of largeIcon variable in .setLargeIcon?

Comment: see now I added conversion on drawable to bitmap also

Comment: When a Drawable doens't have an intrinsic width or height, it doesn't mean it should be displayed as a single colored pixel. Also, the large Bitmap image dimensions should be `android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_width` x `android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_height` (you can retrieve and use these values when creating the Bitmap)